Conserved Noether charge in complex plane
I'm having some problems in understanding charge conservation. I'm reading Polchinski "Introduction to string theory" cap. 2. Here, we are talking about conformal field theory. Specifically, here we are on the 2-dimensional worldsheet, so we move on complex coordinates after Wick-rotating the $0$-coordinate and we make a conformal transformation: $\sigma^2=i\sigma^0$, $z=e^{-i\sigma^1+\sigma^2}$.
A quantity $Q$ is a conserved charge if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\sigma^0}=0$, which, I think, implies after Wick rotation $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\sigma^2}=0$. We are interested in the complex plane, so $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\sigma^2}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial\sigma^2}+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \bar{z}}\frac{\partial \bar{z}}{\partial\sigma^2}=z\partial Q + \bar{z} \bar{\partial} Q=0,$$ where I have used the definition of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ and the notation $\partial=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. Finally, this seems to imply that charge conservation is embedded in the complex frame by the relation $$z\partial Q = - \bar{z} \bar{\partial} Q \tag{1}.$$ This form seems appealing because $z \partial + \bar{z} \bar{\partial}$ is the dilation in the $z$-plane, so $Q$ is independent on the circle on which we evaluate it. Because shifting the radius of circles corresponds in time-shifts, (1) seems equivalent to time independence.
Now, the problems start. At pag. 54, eq (2.6.11) defines the charge as $$Q = \oint_C \frac{dz}{2\pi i} j_z,$$ where $j_z$ is the conserved current from Noether's th. It doesn't fit in the relation (1) (I have checked this taking both the current associated to translations of $X^\mu$ and rigid conformal transformations: the LHS vanishes on-shell because EOM/complex continuity eq., but I don't know how to deal with the RHS), so the first question is

Is this $Q$ really a charge? How to prove its conservation?

In the following page, there is the definition of a different charge $\tilde{Q}$ from $j_\bar{z}$. At page 58 eq 2.7.3, the conserved momentum emerging from translational invariance is defined by adding $Q$ and $\tilde{Q}$.

Is $q=Q + \tilde{Q}$ the true conserved charge? How to prove it? Also this form does not seem to fit into (1).

Also in "Introduction to Conformal Field Theory: With Applications to String Theory" at page 24 the conserved charge is defined through the sum of 2 pieces, one given by $j_z$ and the other $j_\bar{z}$. And a part from be again incompatible (?) with (1), I have tried to deduce this from $$\oint d\sigma^1 j^2$$ substituting $d\sigma^1=\frac{1}{2}(dz+d\bar{z})=dz=d\bar{z}$ (because $d\sigma^2 = 0$) and $j^2=i(j_z-j_\bar{z})$, but there is a different relative sign between the terms $dz j_z$ and $d\bar{z} j_\bar{z}$ in this reference wrt Polchinski's book and I cannot understand from where he find a minus sign.

So, how to write charge conservation in complex coordinates? If the relation (1) is not the good one, which is the correct condition and why does my initial argument provide me the wrong result?

